# In GCC inline asm, how do I allocate and reserve a register? (x86, GDC)

Tags: assembly, gcc, gdc

In GDC x86 in-line asm, I want to reserve a register that is going to be written to so that it does not clash with any other registers written to. (1) How should I do this? The code below works, so it appears, but I get the unpleasant feeling that this is only by good fortunate. (2) Is that so? (3) The xchg instruction does not really want to exchange a register with itself, so how do I ensure that I avoid that by reserving a distinct different register? 4) I feel almost like asking for "allocate register != rbx ? Or in fact more precisely != ( rax|rbx|rcx|rdx )) 5) Do I need to define an unused extra output?

asm pure nothrow @nogc {

```
    ".intel_syntax     " ~ "\n\t" ~

    "mov    %[save], rbx    \n\t" ~ /* save rbx optionally before cpuid trashes it, saved because the GDC compiler prefers it to be so */
    "cpuid                  \n\t" ~ /* writes to rax, rbx, rcx, rdx - and GDC is unhappy about bx */
    "xchg   rbx, %[save]    \n\t" ~ /* restore rbx, the cpuid output rbx value is now returned in save reg */
    
    ".att_syntax        \n"
    : /* outputs : */
            "=a"    ( ret.eax ),        // an lhs ref, write-only
      [ save ]  "=&r"   ( cpuid_rbx_out ),  /* =save - switched over to use (eg rsi) as an output */
                            /* instead of actual rbx */
            "=c"    ( ret.ecx ),
            "=d"    ( ret.edx )
    :   /* inputs : */
            "a"  ( in_eax )     // read
        // no ecx input in this variant
    :   /* no other clobbers */  /* does cpuid set flags? - think not, so no "cc" clobber reqd */
    ;
    }
```

The purpose of this snippet is to simply wrap the cpuid instruction, but also preserve rbx since the compiler is happier that way. If I omit this and merely mark rbx as an output then nothing goes wrong because the compiler does a push rbx / pop rbx outside the asm section. But I thought that a slightly faster trick might be to save rbx in a spare register assuming that there are some free, and return the rbx result from cpuid still but in a different register.

Comment: Are you porting 32-bit code?  I think all 64-bit compilers will let you use `"=b"` as an output; historically GCC wouldn't allow that in 32-bit PIC code since it insisted on using EBX as a pointer to the GOT, but x86-64 has RIP-relative addressing.  And GCC is smarter now, able to use a different register or even re-generate a GOT pointer after asm if it clobbered everything.  Anyway, that's why this code is letting the compiler pick an output register and spending extra `xchg` instructions inside the template to avoid needing an EBX clobber or `"=b"` output.

Comment: `cpuid` is slow, nobody cares about speed. Just let the compiler do whatever it needs to with `rbx`. It might not always `push`/`pop` or might not do it immediately, or it might have saved `rbx` already. Don't know about GDC, but GCC itself provides cpuid built in so you don't need inline asm. Maybe look into that. Also switching syntax is ugly and potentially errors. Another advantage is if you just use the `cpuid` and let the compiler do the registers it will work in either syntax mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes since `rbx` is caller saved according to the ABI it needs to be preserved no matter if it's used for GOT or not.

Comment: @Jester: This is *inline* asm.  If you tell the compiler `RBX` is an output or clobber, the function this eventually inlines into will preserve it. That's the normal thing to do, rather than preserving it yourself, potentially inside a loop. but problem was old `gcc -m32 -fPIC` would complain if you tried to do that.   Also, you can't safely push/pop inside inline asm since that clobbers the red-zone.

Comment: We agree on that :) Just get rid of the `xchg` and let the compiler do its thing.

Comment: @Jester: Right, I was just explaining why 32-bit versions of this code historically needed to exist.  Also, it's easier for a beginner to understand the pieces of the asm statement if they know what it's doing and why.  But yeah, best would be to use an existing CPUID wrapper for GDC.

Comment: I’m not porting 32-bit code. I’ve also done as you suggest, let the compiler handle the preservation of rbx. My intention though was to give the user a more compiler-friendly alternative implementation, and she/he can choose whichever they find better. If this works I wonder if it might be infinitesimally faster than push/pop.

Comment: I understand all of your opinions and had considered these issues already, but you haven’t seen the rest of this small library. I know that cpuid is very slow ~100 clocks, so fine-tuning is not really relevant.

Comment: I don’t know what environment this library code will be run in and don’t know whether or not there will be a red zone. But I didn’t think about the prohibition of push/pop and the red zone thing, so I nearly had a horrible bug there. Thanks for making me aware of this. Is there a way to ask at build-time/compile-time whether or not there is a red zone and query its size?

Comment: In your opinion, is this code buggy?

Comment: I don’t understand how to make xchg pick distinct registers - this is a general question that someone could maybe help me with ?

Comment: Actually, do I need a fake input argument for this, ie to reserve/allocate a register?

Comment: I just noticed a sort-of bug elsewhere in my code. In another alternative routine, I packed the result four 32-bit words into two 64-bit output registers, to give the caller a choice of using 64-bit eg comparison instructions with less effort. Both 32-bit ret and 64-bit ret options are available. I noticed that the compiler was inserting zero-extend instructions on the results after the cpuid. This was because I had used uint32_t variables for the four cpuid outputs and I should have made these 64-bit.

Comment: Reviewers please note that this is a learning exercise for me. It’s part of a library that also offers cached memoized results of common queries that use cpuid. I need to find out which queries (tuples of eax, ecx values) are popular. The cache is populated with all possible query results before main is run, so then the slowness of cpuid isn’t quite so bad. Called in a loop in the per-module static constructor.

Comment: *(3) The xchg instruction does not really want to exchange a register with itself,* - incorrect. `xchg rbx,rbx` is an inefficient NOP (3 uops on Intel, vs. 1 for push or pop https://agner.org/). That's why this "idiom" was safe in 32-bit code.  I hadn't read the full text (last para), funny that you ended up inventing the same workaround they did.  But it's slower, and larger code-size (3 bytes per `xchg`, vs. 1 each for `push`/`pop`). And a function that runs CPUID multiple times to query different leafs will end up with an `xchg` around each one, vs. one push/pop pair for the whole function.

Comment: If a program wants to know something about the CPU, it should query at startup and decode the result into its own global variables that are fast to check, like setting function pointers based on CPU feature flags, or `unsigned cache_line_size = whatever;`.  Is the use-case for memoization when you have multiple libraries (like x264, x265, etc.) that all separately want to do CPU detection to set up their function pointers, etc?  So they'd all separately be calling CPUID functions?  Your idea is kind of like GCC's `__builtin_cpu_supports("avx")` but in general, not just features.

Comment: If `mov` was a much better strategy than `push`/`pop`, hopefully compilers would already be using it.  But to be fair, it only affects inline asm, and cases like `cmpxchg16b`, or (in 32-bit code) RSI and RDI for rep-string ops.  So it's not unreasonable to wonder if it's a missed optimization vs. not being more efficient.  CPUID is fully serializing, having to flush even front-end and drain the ROB+RS, so it dwarfs the cost of cheap push/pop, and with push happening soon after `call` pushed a return address, it's not significant extra work to wait for with a serializing instruction.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/bfn1Mvoac shows 3 ways in C: normal, mov/xchg, and mov/cpuid/mov/mov.  (fewer uops but more code size).  See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info and documentation.  The trick of using a dummy C variable to let the compiler pick a temporary register is mentioned in some other inline asm Q&As I think.

Comment: I have given functions that offer memoized-access cpuid queries, which only consult the result-cache in a static. I’ve also given direct access to cpuid in wrappers for the user to use for other purposes and one direct-cpuid wrapper specially intended to get the serialisation effects of cpuid. These differ in their use of the D pure attribute iirc.